# Migrating from firebase

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, backend, react-fullstack

I will start developing my e-commerce website soon however, I don't have experience in backend. So I'm considering to use firebase. But my real concern is, , is firebase good option on long term? Is it easy to migrate to mongodb and node js or is it better to write my own backend from the beginning?

Comment: And also is the free plan limits is enough for the long term? so is it likely to exceed the limits quickly and if so will it be cost-efficient comparing to MongoDB

Comment: Your Question is based on opinion/advise, which isn't a good fit for Stack overflow, since there is no correct answer. Also, Stack Overflow is for programming problems, not rate-limits, pricing or promoting software/commercial solutions, which is likely to be in some of the Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using firebase if the features are useful to you:

- authentication
- noSQL database
- storage
- in-app messaging

It is a good option long-term if don't hit the upper limits of the [free plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) for a long time. This is almost always the case for new unknown projects.

Because of the noSQL nature, switching to mongoDB is straight-forward. The real question is if you are already experienced with setting up and using node.js with mongoDB. You are better served with what you already know.

Use Firebase if you have no significant experience with the alternatives.